# Python: Allow repeating regex while only allowing 1 hyphen between commas

Tags: python, regex

I am really stuck on regex. For example, I have:

```
^(\d+)(?:[-,](\d+)(?:[,/](\d+))*?)*$
```

This allows me to match any comma deliminated number from 0-9 repeatedly.
`i.e 4,5,6,6,7,8,8 == match` However, it also allows a number to be separated by a hyphen multiple times in between commas, which I do not want.
`i.e 4-4-4-4-4,4,4-4 == match`

How can I change this pattern so it allows for:
`4-4,5,5`
but not `4-4-4-4`

Answer (score 2):

Assuming that `,` and `/` are valid token delimiters:

**Regex**

```
^(?:(?:^|[/,])\d+(?:-\d+)?)+$
```

- `(?:^|[/,])` matches at the beggining of the string, or requires a token delimiter.
- `\d+` matches any positive integer.
- `(?:-\d+)?` allows an optional hyphen and integer.
- This is all enclosed in a `(?:non-capturing group)` in order to repeat it with `+` (at least once).

**Code**

```
import re
pattern = re.compile(r'^(?:(?:^|[/,])\d+(?:-\d+)?)+$')
text = "4,4-5,6,6,7,8,9-8,1234-1,4321"

re.search(pattern, text)
```

Answer (score 1):

Note that `\d+` matches strings of one digit **or more**. If you only want single digits, replace `\d+` with `\d`.

My original one was based on a misinterpretation of the question.

<del>Try</del>

```
^(\d+)(?:(?:[,/](\d+))*?[-,](\d+)(?:[,/](\d+))*?)$
```

<del>This may change the numberings of the groups that you find if that is important to you.</del>

<del>Also, the it allows you to replace some of your slashes with commas, as your original regex does. I am not sure if this is your intention.</del>

Comment: Doesn't match `'4-4,5-6,3,4,7-1000,43,55-140'` ;)

Comment: Ooooh, I misinterpreted this question. That makes a lot of sense.

Answer (score 1):

You could simply clarify your pattern by breaking them down into the standalone units, i.e. either a number or range, which is represented by `(\d+(?:-\d+)?)`, and repeat the pattern again with a comma in front and have a `*` match, resulting in something like this

```
^(\d+(?:-\d+)?)(?:,(\d+(?:-\d+)?))*$
```

Example usage in python.

```
>>> patt = re.compile(r'^(\d+(?:-\d+)?)(?:,(\d+(?:-\d+)?))*$')
>>> patt.search('4,5')
<_sre.SRE_Match object at 0x7fba38759360>
>>> patt.search('4-4')
<_sre.SRE_Match object at 0x7fba387593e8>
>>> patt.search('4-4-4-4')
>>> patt.search('4-4,5-6,3,4,7-1000,43,55-140')
<_sre.SRE_Match object at 0x7fba38759360>
```